# Correct norms for the rings $\Bbb Z[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-5}}{2}]$ and $\Bbb Z[\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}]$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If I am not mistaken the norms for the rings
$\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{5}]$ are $a^2 + 5 b^2$ and $ a^2 - 5 b^2$, resp.

How about $\Bbb Z[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-5}}{2}]$ and
$\Bbb Z[\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}]$?

I'm in doubt of these.  Same norm ?

OR $\frac{a^2 + 5 b^2}{4}$ and  $ \frac{a^2 - 5 b^2}{4}$ because of the $2$ ?

But those are not even always integers ?

Using the matrix representation suggests this though.

I am confused.

Comment: Use single dollar signs for small formulas that can be in-line. Making every formula a display makes it hard to read.

Comment: Observe that $\alpha=(1+\sqrt{-5})/2$ is not an algebraic integer. You can still look at the ring $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$, but in there are elements like $\alpha(1-\alpha)=3/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The norm of an element $a + b\sqrt{\pm 5}$ is $a^2 \mp 5b^2$ when $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, since the Galois conjugate of $a + b\sqrt{\pm 5}$ is $a - b\sqrt{\pm 5}$ and the norm is given by multiplying all Galois conjugates.

The elements of the ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{  5}}{2}\right]$ are all of the form $a + b \sqrt{ 5}$, where $a, b$ are either both integers or both of the form $a = \frac{c}{2}, b = \frac{d}{2}$ where $c, d$ are odd integers. You can check that the norm is an integer even in the second case, which is expected since $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$ is the ring of integers of an algebraic number field. The ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-5}}{2}\right]$ is not integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, so we don't expect norms to be integers.

Comment: Right ! that solves it. Accepted. +1

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yeah. But the main insight was given so I accepted anyway. I consider it a detail (in this context !)